# trying to link two cpp files with a header

Tags: class, visual-c++, header, linker-errors

I'm trying to call a function from a cpp file (with a list of functions) in another cpp file, I'm using a header file to set the function prototype in both cpp files, my problem is that I'm getting this LNK2019 error. I don't know what i'm doing wrong. I've been going back and forth between a few variations, the current one seems to be the most correct based on what i've read. I've been working on this for hours, reading a bunch of threads, but nothing seems to explain this problem, i'm using microsoft visual studio 2012

this is the header file, Rectangle.h

```
#pragma once
class Rectangle
{
private:
    int width, height; 
    double gravWidth, gravHeight;
public:
    Rectangle();
    double getAreaBig();
    double getAreaSmall();
    int getPerimeter();
    void getLength(int b);
    void getWidth(int a);
    int setLength();
    int setWidth();

    ~Rectangle();
};
```

this is the cpp file containing the functions, Rectangle.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Rectangle.h"


using namespace std;


Rectangle::Rectangle()
{
    width = 1;
    height = 1;
    gravWidth = .5;
    gravHeight = .5;
}
double Rectangle::getAreaBig ()
{
    return double ((width * height) - (gravWidth *  gravHeight));
}

double Rectangle::getAreaSmall()
{
    return ((gravWidth) * ( gravHeight));
}

int Rectangle::getPerimeter()
{
    return (2 * (width + height));
}

void Rectangle::getLength(int b)
{
    height = b;
    gravWidth = (1/2 * width);
}
void Rectangle::getWidth(int a)
{
    width = a;
    gravHeight = (1/2 * height);
}

int Rectangle::setLength()
{
    return height;
}
int Rectangle::setWidth()
{
    return width;
}
```

what follows is the app.cpp file, this is where i'm getting the errors, italics are where the errors seem to be pointing too

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Rectangle.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstddef> 

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int const  WIDTH = 10;
    setprecision(2);

    int length = 0;
    int width = 0;

    cin >> width;
    cin >> length;

    Rectangle garden;
    Rectangle gravel;


    garden.getLength(length);
    garden.getWidth(width);

    cout << "Length of lawn: " << garden.setLength() << "Width of lawn: " << garden.setWidth();
    cout << "Cost of grass: " << garden.getAreaBig();
    cout << "Length of gravel: ";
    cout << "Width of gravel: ";
    cout << "Cost of gavel: ";
    system ("pause");


}
```

Comment: *i'm sorry i forgot to comment out some of the code, if it's too hard to follow, i will edit

Comment: I also learned that i was not calling the function correctly, this seemed to really help fix the problem, thanks to those who replied what follows is the code that alleviates my cout problem          *Rectangle garden;
Rectangle gravel;
garden.getLength(length);
garden.getWidth(width);
gravel.getLength(length);
gravel.getWidth(width);*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that I see is that you are not instantiating the rectangles.

Answer (score 0):

What about defining

> ~Rectangle();

somewhere? If your destructor is not going to do anything, you can just provide an empty body in the header file.

> ~Rectangle() {};

(And just in case, make it virtual, it's always a good habit.)

Comment: I did that and it fixed that specific error, I also realized that i was not properly calling the function, thank you

Comment: * as an aside, how would i make it virtual?